# Chrome App With TitleBar color

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a chrome app that opens in a new window.

I've got a basic manifest like this

```
{
  "name": "My App",
   "description": "Application Description",
   "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
       "scripts": ["background.js"]
     }
  }
}
```

The background.js then simply launches my index.html page and away my app runs, here's the background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
        "bounds": {
            "width": 1024,
            "height": 800
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is my layout sorta doesn't clash well with the default 'plain white' window chrome that the default chrome has.  I've seen other apps change this to show a more standard window app.  I have no clue how to do this and can't find anything in the documentation.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's some pictures for an example

GistBox with a more standard window chrome

[image: GistBox window chrome]

My App with the 'white default' window chrome

[image: My App White Default]

How do I get my window chrome the more standard window chrome like GistBox uses?

(btw I'm using Win7, latest version of stable chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the creator of GistBox.

There is a general confusion between [Chrome Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) and [Chrome Hosted Apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide). The app you are creating is a Packaged App (which has a background.js). The GistBox app you installed is a Chrome Hosted App, which is basically a shortcut to a webpage with access to some basic Chrome APIs. It's manifest looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "GistBox",
    "description": "The beautiful way to organize code snippets.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "https://app.gistboxapp.com"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "https://app.gistboxapp.com",
            "container": "panel",
            "width": 1200,
            "height": 768
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "chrome-icon-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        // permissions
    ]
}
```

[GistBox Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gistbox-desktop/pdjgfbgklbmmigkmmdbbhfchdldngkml) was created as a Chrome Packaged App and pops up with the same white titlebar yours does:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that Hosted Apps had to be in an actual window/tab of chrome, and only packaged apps could have their own window...I was wrong.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If you want to have complete control over your app window's appearance, you can set frame:none in chrome.app.window.create(). However, then you'll have full responsibility for all the window controls, which might be more work than you want.